# Get drop down to appear when hovering single menu item, not entire menu

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I currently have a `section` that is a flex box. I am trying to get a drop down menu to appear when I mouse over the `Vs` div.  Unfortunately, this div is inside a `section` tag and the drop down menu won't appear.

The way the code is currently set up causes the drop down menu to appear when I mouse over any part of the section. I want the drop down menu to only appear when I mouse over the `Vs.` div.

Here is an image of the section.

[image]

```css
.line {
  height: 4px;
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.home {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.m {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.logout {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.dropDown:hover ~ .dropDownContent {
  display: block;
}
.dropDownContent {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="dropDown">
  <div class="home">Home</div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="m">Reports</div>
  <div class="m dropDownVs">Vs.</div>
  <div class="logout"> <a href="url"> Log Out </a> 
  </div>
</section>

<div class="dropDownContent">
  <ul>
    <li>name 1</li>
    <li>name 2</li>
    <li>name 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Bonus: Any suggestions on aligning the drop down directly below the Vs. div and suggestions for selecting the drop down items when the mouse is off the Vs. div would be appreciated. Currently when I mouse off the section the dropdown disappears and a user is unable to select anything.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: I put the code into a fiddle it gives me a slightly different result than my text editor. Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/havxxkpc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have the drop-down menu positioned as a sibling to the main menu. It's better to nest the drop-down within the related main menu item. Try this:

```css
.dropDownVs:hover .dropDownContent {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.dropDownContent {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  height: 4px;
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.home {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.m {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.logout {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="dropDown">
  <div class="home">Home</div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="m">Reports</div>
  <div class="m dropDownVs">Vs.
    <ul class="dropDownContent">
      <li>name 1</li>
      <li>name 2</li>
      <li>name 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="logout"> <a href="url"> Log Out </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but I have a couple of questions. I have seen things like this .dropDownVs > li {       }  in my google searches but I don't understand what they mean, so I had avoided using them. What is happening when you use the > like that?

Comment: The `>` is a child selector. It targets elements that are children of an element. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp